# read from excel sheet in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I need help about Matlab and Excel sheet work.
Can any body tell how to only read the location of cell in excel sheet by using Matlab
that is if I have anything written in any cell let say at " B3 ".
and I want to use this B3 in my code.so how am I suppose to get that location of data?

Comment: reading the `help` sometimes may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

From the Matlab documentation:

> Example 3 — Selecting a Range of Data
>
> To import only rows 4 and 5 from worksheet 1, specify the range as 'A4:B5':

```
A = xlsread('testdata2.xls', 1, 'A4:B5')

A =
    4    9
    5   NaN
```